# Adding Varibles to a path? BATCH

Tags: batch-file

Okay, so I'm programming a launcher for Minecraft and I'm trying to add logs to it.

```
echo %TIME% %DATE% Launched > "%DRIVE%\DATA\LOGS\Log Time %TIME% Date %DATE%.txt"
```

It says it can't find the file specified!

EDIT: Literally a duplicate of [my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40472534/batch-closing-if-a-string-has-a-space-in-it).

Comment: Can you provide more of the batch file code?

Comment: So `%DRIVE%` points to a non-existent location or it is empty.

Comment: Also, don't put spaces in path names if you can at all help it. It won't make a difference here, but it's good advice in general.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? By default you are able to use variables in a path name, however based on what scarce code you have given it would seem as if you are using it incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that you want to save a file with name has time and date !

```
@echo off
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims==" %%i in (`wmic os get LocalDateTime /VALUE 2^>NUL`) do if '.%%i.'=='.LocalDateTime.' set ldt=%%j
set ldt=%ldt:~8,2%-%ldt:~10,2%_%ldt:~6,2%-%ldt:~4,2%-%ldt:~0,4%.txt
echo %ldt%
echo %TIME% %DATE% Launched > %ldt%
Start "" %ldt%
pause
```