# Batch closing if a string has a space in it?

Tags: windows, batch-file

so for some reason when

```
set /p content="[-]"
timeout 1 >nul
if %content% == Quit goto QQIITT
if %content% == quit goto QQIITT
if %content% == Help goto HALPP
if %content% == help goto HALPP
timeout 1 >nul
```

if I type something like "echo HELLO" (in the program) it will not work, it does this when ever i type something with a space, is there anyone who can help? (I am making a batch code editor and if it does not match the if statements it will go to a script that saves the changes)

Comment: one of many [duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22945480/batch-goto-was-unexpected-at-this-time-error/22946040#22946040)

Comment: Read the help for the `IF` command.  I bet you will be able to remove a few lines of code after you are done reading it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
"%content%" == "Quit"
```

Note this will break if you pass through a double quote in your input.

Batch blindly replaces variables so in your example the code renders as

```
if echo HELLO == HELP
```

Comment: Thank you, I did not take that into account.